# how to pass parameter of the destination to middleware in gin/golang

Tags: go, authentication, jwt

My problem in short is:
I send my auth token as a parameter to my destination api and it seems like middleware can not access that. How can I access the parameter since the middleware needs that to check the auth conditions?

I am trying to implement a simple authentication/authorization application.
I know that it is common to set auth token in coockies, however, in my use-case, I need it to be implemented differently.

The implementation is: login returns auth token in response body and anytime authentication token is required, it is sent as a parameter `"authorization"` to the application.

here is the code for my user routers :

```
func UserRoute(router *gin.Engine) {
    user := router.Group("/user")
    {
        user.POST("/signup", controllers.SignUp)
        user.POST("/login", controllers.Login)

        user.GET("/validate", middleware.RequireAuth, controllers.Validate)
    }
}
```

`validate` function in `usercontrollers.go`:

```
func Validate(c *gin.Context) {
    user, _ := c.Get("user")
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "message": user,
    })
}
```

here is the request I send

```
http://localhost:6000/user/validate?authorization=[My-JWT-Token]
```

Now when I try to read my auth parameter and use it in my middleware it seems like it does not actually exist:

```
func RequireAuth(c *gin.Context) {
    confs, _ := configs.LoadConfig()
    tokenString := c.Param("authorization")

    if tokenString == "" {
       // this abort case always happens
       c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }
}
```

Comment: You example request doesn't suggest it contains an "authorization" query parameter, just a "naked" jwt token. And `c.Param` is used for path parameters only, if I'm not mistaken, it is not used for query parameters. Use [`c.Query`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Query) for query parameters.

Comment: that jwt token parameter I send, I send with the key "authorization". here is a sample 
`http://localhost:6000/user/validate?authorization=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NjM5OTkxMTYsInN1YiI6NH0.rTdzS05u23IA6Yy7JMafg_4QZt4ADoMY6tRLwgRbP1Y`  @mkopriva

Comment: you were right this fixed my issue. However in all my other get requests, I read the parameters the same way using `Param`  and in my postman I add them all in Query Params section and it works. What is different in this case? @mkopriva

Comment: I don't know, I do not use gin so I can't confirm whether or not `c.Param` can be used to retrieve query parameters. But based on the documentation it shouldn't, see: [path parameters](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#readme-parameters-in-path) vs [query parameters](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#readme-querystring-parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. ctx.Request.URL.Query().Get("authorization")
2. ctx.Query("authorization")
```